# exercises for serratus and oblique muscles?

Tags: weightlifting, muscle-mass

I am looking for some weight lifting exercises for the area under the pectoralis muscles, namely the serratus and oblique. I heard this is beneficial for people who play basketball, volleyball and tennis...

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best tool for the job is the ab wheel.  It's a $10 piece of equipment you can get from Walmart, but you will need to work up to being able to use it.  However, getting to using it in it's truly [beast skill](http://www.beastskills.com/tutorials/tutorials/37) way is very difficult.

[David Lasnier has some progression](http://davidlasnier.com/tag/ab-wheel-rollout) to get your abs ready for the wheel.